# How to develop an android app on EclipseIDE using Maven framework?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I have been stuck with this problem for 3 days. I want to develop an android app in Maven framework using Eclipse. I have no idea about Maven framework. I am using Apache maven. I followed the instructions in installing, it's showing the version etc, but when I try to set path to repo, I am getting this

```
C:\Users\377759>cd mvn -Declipse.workspace=<C:\Users\377759\Desktop\Repo> eclipse:add-maven-repo
Access is denied.
```

And if give the path without angular brackets, this is what I get..

```
C:\Users\377759>mvn -Declipse.workspace=C:\Users\377759\Desktop\Repo eclipse:add-maven-repo
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'eclipse'.
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
[INFO] Repository 'central' will be blacklisted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 01 05:38:44 GMT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/3M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\377759>
```

Why is this?? What do I do?? Actually I need to know the basics, like how to package my files in maven, the functions of different files etc. Can anyone plzzz help??
Thanks a looot in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

To access your local repository you need the path to that folder. Just remember that Subversion expects all repository paths in the form `file:///C:/SVNRepository/`

Also, in your Maven `settings.xml`, this can be found in your **Maven_Installation_Folder\conf**, check out the following:

- Proxy, if required should be specified to connect to Internet.
- If you have a Local repository, define it here. (You can see the sample definitions there itself)

For Maven basic usage, read the documentation from **Apache Maven Website**

Comment: Hey,Thanks for replying..Its still the same:(!!